# writing handlers for custom framework

Tags: swift, frameworks, handler, code-reuse

I am creating a framework that include some button actions. but the thing is i cannot write code in action as i have to use this framework anywhere when required. it can either be used in one or multiple application. the thing is i have to handle the actions and too write handlers for these purpose. i do not have idea how the things get tackle. if i have to right handler for below action that it will be used in any of the application as plugin. how i can do this

example code:

```
@IBAction func btnShowAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    let bundle = Bundle(for: WorkspaceTabVC.self)
    
    let workspaceTabVC = WorkspaceTabVC(nibName: "WorkspaceTabVC", bundle: bundle)
   workspaceTabVC.showBackButton = false

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(workspaceTabVC, animated: true)
    
}
```

Comment: You can put this button action inside the UIViewController extension and then bind from any view controller or just create a function inside the extension and call from anywhere.

Comment: the thing is i ve to use this framework in any of my project. my focus is reuseability. cannot handle the scenario with action. i ve to perform it by some other method. the same thing but with different way but code independent.the thing is may be i need may not push it all the time, i can present/add as child or do what ever.

Comment: @RajaKishan can you please share example code of extension for doing this and how to call. i cant understand it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly, but if you want your framework to trigger an application specific code, you might want to take a look at the delegate pattern (or any alternatives like closures).